# Xperf through a Fast Boot cycle

Tags: windows, windows-10, etw, xperf, wpr

I need to write a small program/script to run Xperf to collect certain ETW events (OS and drivers) through a Windows Fast Boot (aka Fast Startup) cycle.

How would I be able to preserve my program and xperf processes, so they can collect events until the moment OS hibernates and as soon as OS is initializing again? Windows Performance Recorder (WPR) can do that but I need to write my own for other reasons.

Comment: why do you need to reinvent the wheel? if there something that works, just use it

Comment: May have license and distribution issue, thought not certain yet. Regardless, couldn't that simply be good to find out how?

Comment: the WPT has redist MSIs that you can include in your tool. So this is no issue